# Progress 4GL: Formatting decimals through temp-table declaration

Tags: progress-4gl

I'm trying to format decimal's to round to the nearest hundredth with a temp-table declaration similar to this.

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE foo
FIELD random-decimal AS DECIMAL FORMAT "->>>,>>>,>>>.99".
```

The end result is displayed on a report through which I'm using the following to output:

```
EXPORT STREAM sStream DELIMITER ',' foo.
```

This does not seem to work as I'm intending it to.  I'm still receiving values like this: 0.000073.

Does anyone have any insight to what I'm doing wrong?  I was unable to find anything for this specific case anyone online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FORMAT has no impact on storage.  It is only a "hint" for default display and input purposes.

What you want is the "decimals" field attribute:

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE foo
FIELD random-decimal AS DECIMAL decimals 2 FORMAT "->>>,>>>,>>>.99".

create foo.
random-decimal = 1.12345.

display random-decimal format ">.9999".
```